# Concat two Scala Array

Tags: arrays, scala, join, concatenation

I have two Array like this:

```
val l1 = Array((1,2,3), (6,2,-3), (6,2,-4))
val l2 = Array("a","b","c")
```

I would like to put values of l2 in array at the same position in l1 and obtain a final array like that

```
Array((1,2,3,"a"), (6,2,-3,"b"), (6,2,-4,"c"))
```

I was thinking about something like:

```
val l3 = l1.map( code...)
```

But i don't know how to iterate on l2 during map on l1.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining collections in this way can be done with [Zipping](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#zip).

```
l1.zip(l2).map{ case (x,y) => (x._1, x._2, x._3, y) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to `map` over the indexes used to access elements from each array.

```
(0 until l1.length).map{ idx =>
  (l1(idx)._1, l1(idx)._2, l1(idx)._3, l2(idx))
}
res0: IndexedSeq[(Int, Int, Int, Char)] = Vector((1,2,3,a), (6,2,-3,b), (6,2,-4,c))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You should use `l1.indices` instead of `(0 until l1.length)` to prevent off-by-one errors.

Comment: @corvus_192, an excellent suggestion, but marios still has the better solution.